# Не знаю как добавить данные в созданную таблицу Word c++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, ms-word

Добрый вечер. Не получается добавить данные в таблицу MSWord.
Код с++:

```
Variant Word,Table,Cell,Document;
AnsiString FilePath;
FilePath = "C:\\Rasp.rtf";
Word = CreateOleObject("Word.Application");    // открываю Word.
Word.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);   // делаю видимость документа.
// И чтобы не создавать новый лист, например (Word.OlePropertyGet("Documents").OleProcedure("Add"); ) открываю уже созданный на диске С:\ документ формата rtf, уже с готовой отформатированной таблицей.
Word.OlePropertyGet("Documents").OleFunction("Open", WideString(FilePath));
```

Не знаю как добавить данные в ячейку таблицы ? Вообще можно добавлять данные в уже созданную таблицу? Сколько примеров просмотрел. Все только для начало создают а затем выполняют какие либо действия.

Answer (score 1):

Все сделал. Код конечно честно стыренный с другого форума, но сам понял что сделал. В готовой таблице, где именно нужно вставить текст, написал букву. Затем выделил ее и перешел на вкладку вставка->закладка, дал имя закладке и добавил.

```
Variant vApp,vDocs, vDoc, vBookmarks, vBookmark, vSelection, vRange;
AnsiString FilePath,str;

FilePath = "C:\\Rasp.rtf";
vApp = CreateOleObject("Word.Application");
vApp.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);
vDocs = vApp.OlePropertyGet("Documents");
vDocs.OleFunction("Add", WideString(FilePath));
vDoc = vDocs.OleFunction("Item",1);
vDoc.OleProcedure("Activate");
vBookmarks = vDoc.OlePropertyGet("Bookmarks");
vBookmark = vBookmarks.OleFunction("Item", WideString("zakla"));  // имя закладки
vBookmark.OleProcedure("Select");
vSelection = vApp.OlePropertyGet("Selection");
vSelection.OlePropertySet("Text", WideString("Козлов Андрей"));  // вставляемый текст
vRange = vDoc.OleFunction("Range", 0, 0);
vRange.OleProcedure(_T("Select"));
```

На всякий случай библиотеки:

```
#include <OleServer.hpp>
#include <ComObj.hpp>
#include <utilcls.h>
```